Understanding virtual environments on VSCode vs Anaconda vs Global Python base (Why does my AppKit installations work for Conda but not rest)
I was trying to install AppKit and came across numerous errors of meta package not existing and pycairo not being able to be downloaded. I went through stackoverflow and tried different pip install AppKit, pip install pyobjc and then also tried brew install pygobjc3 etc.
And even though it said AppKit was successfully installed (and I uninstalled and reinstalled to be safe) I was unable to do "from AppKit import NSWorkspace" because AppKit was an unrecognized import. I fixed the issue by moving my interpreter from 3.12.1 virtual environment to my 3.11.5 anaconda environment. But, I checked my other interpreters 3.11.5 base and 3.9.6 python and AppKit was also not recognized.
Could anybody explain why this is? Or is there any documentation I can read to understand the differences between them as well? I'm fairly new to coding and I've been struggling a bit with setting up my projects because I get so confused.

if you can install it with pip then maybe use /full/path/to/python -m pip install ... instead of pip install ..., and later use the same path to run code /full/path/to/python script.py - this way it will install module for Python which you use to run code.

your problem could be caused by installing AppKit to the global environment. You can choose to use pip uninstall pyobjc-framework-AppKit to uninstall AppKit. Then select NSWorkspace and use the shortcut ctrl+shift+p (window and Linux) or cmd-shift+p (macOS) to enter the command panel. Then use the Python: Select Interpreter command in the command palette to select the interpreter of the virtual environment you want to enter. After entering the virtual environment, use the command pip install pyobjc-framework-AppKit to install AppKit.You can refer to the following article to learn how to set up and use the environment.
